# Magento 2 - How to run fast command line setup:di:compile?

Tags: magento2, cli, di

How to run fast command line `setup:di:compile.`

I was waiting so long, if can you show me why?

[image]

Comment: Wow this is really annoying if you have waiting for that long. how many module that you have installed here ? I just want to know

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, unfortunately apart from improving your hardware there is no way you can make that command faster.

This command is the Magento code compilation.

> Code compilation consists of all of the following in no particular
>   order:
>
> - Application code generation (factories, proxies, and so on)
> - Area
>     configuration aggregation (that is, optimized dependency injection
>     configurations per area)
> - Interceptor generation (that is, optimized
>     code generation of interceptors)
> - Interception cache generation
> - Repositories code generation (that is, generated code for APIs)
> - Service data attributes generation (that is, generated extension
>     classes for data objects)

Because of all those actions the compiler needs to take, it has to take time.

Comment: Have anything method to compile only one module ?

Comment: @MagentoOdoo.com well that's a different question, fortunately it has already been answered you can find it here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95255/magento-2-run-setupdicompile-only-a-specific-module